# Запуск .jar файлов на линукс

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, jar

Не могу запустить программу .jar формата в терминале, и в графическом интерфейсе. При запуске через терминал выдает ошибку

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:242)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be 
cast to java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader
at launcher.helper.JVMHelper.<clinit>(JVMHelper.java:26)
... 1 more
```

При запуске через графический интерфейс ничего не происходит. Кто в теме, помогите пожалуйста, буду очень признателен.

Comment: Приложение, которое вы пытаетесь запустить, несовместимо с Java девятой и более новых версий.

Comment: Спасибо, я уже нашел решение проблемы. Надо было установить проприетарную версию от Oracle.